# How to fire one directive instance

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I haven't so much experience in Angular, so can anybody help:

I have some instances of directive. When I clicked on pink square, text changed in all instances. How I can change text just in that instance where I clicked before?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <style>
        .placeToClick {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<my-dir index="1"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="2"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="3"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="4"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="5"></my-dir>
<div class="placeToClick"></div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.directive("myDir", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                index: '='
            },
            template: '<div style="width: 100px; border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; margin: 20px;" ng-click="changeText(index)">{{text}}</div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, atts){
                var place = angular.element(document.querySelector('.placeToClick'));
                scope.text = 'Some text';

                place.on('click', function(){
                    scope.text = 'Text is changed';
                    elem.css('color', 'red');
                    scope.$apply();
                });

                scope.changeText = function(index){
                    scope.text = 'Text in index ' + index + ' changed'
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have one button and two directive usage. You have two binding on the same button so this is logic behavior. Which of directive You need to change? "How I can change text just in one of them" how You want to choose which?

Comment: Add directive html code

Comment: any instance of them

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <style>
        .placeToClick {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<my-dir index="1"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="2"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="3"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="4"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="5"></my-dir>
<div class="placeToClick"></div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.directive("myDir", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                index: '='
            },
            template: '<div style="width: 100px; border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; margin: 20px;" ng-click="changeText(index)">{{text}}</div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, atts){
                var place = angular.element(document.querySelector('.placeToClick[index="'+scope.index+'"]'));
                scope.text = 'Some text';

                place.on('click', function(){
                    scope.text = 'Text is changed';
                    elem.css('color', 'red');
                    console.log('dg');
                    scope.$apply();
                });

                scope.changeText = function(index){
                    scope.text = 'Text in index ' + index + ' changed'
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div class="placeToClick"></div> has no attribute index it must be <div class="placeToClick" data-index="2"></div>  - example 2 index. This was 1 point of my answer.

Comment: but I need for every instance I clicked to first instance -> text in first instance changed to "Text in index  1 changed" ->clicked to square and text in first instance changed to 'Text is changed' and so on for every one

Comment: and as I've understood you in <div class="placeToClick"></div> has to be one special index

Comment: You never writed want to click on instance. I was asking which instance, and answer was any of them, and should be clicked instance.

Comment: oh, in that case I'm sorry!, how can I do this thing?

Comment: Check my next answer

Answer (score 0):

Add global variable ( very quick solution only for this situation ):

```
window.currentIndex=0;
```

Change code of link method:

```
    var place = angular.element(document.querySelector('.placeToClick'));
    place.css('cursor', 'pointer')
    scope.text = 'Some text';

    elem.on("click",function(){

      currentIndex=scope.index; //set this is current

    });

    place.on('click', function(){
        if (scope.index==currentIndex){

         //ok we are current so do the work
         scope.text = 'Text is changed';
         elem.css('color', 'red');
         scope.$apply();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <style>
        .placeToClick {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: lightcoral;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<my-dir index="1"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="2"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="3"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="4"></my-dir>
<my-dir index="5"></my-dir>
<div class="placeToClick"></div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.directive("myDir", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                index: '='
            },
            template: '<div style="width: 100px; border: 2px solid black; padding: 5px; margin: 20px;" ng-click="changeText(index)">{{text}}</div>',
            link: function(scope, elem, atts){
                window.currentIndex = 0;
                var place = angular.element(document.querySelector('.placeToClick[index="'+scope.index+'"]'));
                scope.text = 'Some text';

                place.on('click', function(){
                    if(scope.index = window.currentIndex){
                        scope.text = 'Text is changed';
                        elem.css('color', 'red');
                        console.log('dg');
                        scope.$apply();
                    }

                });

                scope.changeText = function(index){
                    scope.text = 'Text in index ' + index + ' changed'
                    window.currentIndex = index;
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing

Comment: This is not my answer, this is some parts of my answer but it is wrong.

Comment: please set my Answer as correct and arrow up. Thanks and good luck.